# Is it possible to use Django F() expressions for atomic updates together with full_clean()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I've just discovered that fields assigned with Django `F()` expressions fail to validate. I modified example from [the Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields):

```
>>> product = Product.objects.get(name='Venezuelan Beaver Cheese')
>>> product.number_sold = F('number_sold') + 1
>>> product.full_clean() # My addition.
>>> product.save()
```

And I'm getting: `ValidationError: {'number_sold': [u"'(+: (DEFAULT: ), 0)' value must be an integer."]}`. Indeed, number sold is not an integer, but an instance of `django.db.models.expressions.ExpressionNode`.

Is there a way around this? All my models extend a base class that automatically calls `full_clean()` on each save and I really like to keep this base class but be able to use atomic updates.

Comment: I think you will need to lift full_clean out of django source and write your own implementation that presumes that ExpressionNode values are always valid.

Answer (score -2):

You problem is that you are trying to save a non integer value in an integer field.

The field `number_sold` is expected an integer in your case.

I would assume that `F('number_sold')` references an empty field.

Try to replace `F('number_sold') + 1` with something hardcoded such as 1.

If that work, let me know and I can supply logic to avoid your error.

Comment: I don't think it is the case. number_sold is a models.IntegerField(default=0). Also if I remove full_clean(), save() the value and then reread the object, number_sold is correctly increased (becomes 1).